# remove custom post type ulr

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I have a custom post type called portfolio with three categories. If i make post with it, the url looks like this. http://skateflix.se/?portfolio=route-one.

Every fix i tried, every plugin gives me this: http://skateflix.se/feeds/route-one where feed is the category. this takes me to the wrong post, nor sure if its an archive template or something similar. What i want is simply removing the custom post type slug.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to your use of `feed`, which is both a reserved keyword, and an existing URL rewrite.

e.g. RSS feeds etc:

```
example.com/feed/rss2
```

You need to change your rewrite rules to use something other than 'feed' in your URL. The same goes for any taxonomies or post types that try to call themselves 'feed'.

Comment: I´s actually feeds that are the correct category slug. Updated my question.